# Images not resizing properly

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

So yes i'm building a game. From the start i forgot to put screen resizing. And know i'm trying to include it. I got almost everything working it resizes images but they get wierd.

Screen setup

```
size = [1600, 1000]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1600, 1000), HWSURFACE | DOUBLEBUF | RESIZABLE)


pygame.display.set_caption('#Vote me for the ruler of the world!!!')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
```

What program does when window gets resized

```
elif event.type == VIDEORESIZE:###########IF WINDOW GETS REZISED
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(event.dict['size'], HWSURFACE | DOUBLEBUF | RESIZABLE)
    pygame.display.flip()
    if GUIstatus == 1:
        screen.fill((color,color,color))
        screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(spaceGUI, event.dict['size']),(0,0))
        screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(screenMonitor,event.dict['size']),(0,0))
        screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(button,event.dict['size']),(1425,10))
        screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(button,event.dict['size']),(1425,75))
        screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(button,event.dict['size']),(1425,140))
        screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(text_button1,event.dict['size']),(1436, 30))
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Picture examples
[Normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8C3CP.png)   ,   [Wierd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzt8X.png)

So what is happening here?

**EDIT**
This is the code for original image drawing. (main loop)

```
done = False
while done == False:
    pygame.event.pump()
    mouse_x,mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()


    timer += 1
    if timer > 99:
        timer = 0

    if GUIstatus == 1:  ####HERE IS THE ORIGINAL IMAGE DRAWING
        screen.blit(spaceGUI,(0,0))
        screen.blit(screenMonitor,(0,0))
        screen.blit(button,(1425,10))
        screen.blit(button,(1425,75))
        screen.blit(button,(1425,140))
        screen.blit(text_button1, (1436, 30))

        if techTreeRect.collidepoint(mouse_x,mouse_y) and event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            print("techtree")

        if contactsRect.collidepoint(mouse_x,mouse_y) and event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
           print("Contacts")
           GUIstatus = 3
           screen.fill((color,color,color))
```

Comment: It looks like the background isn't getting redrawn. Is `color` defined? Does using `screen.fill((255, 255, 255))` change anything?

Comment: It looks like you're drawing both the scaled and the normal versions. My guess is that you're drawing before this code in your game loop; that this code isn't the only time you're blitting to the screen.

Comment: @WyattIsrael color is defined at the start i use `screen.fill((color, color, color))` Because on the start of the program there is like smooth transaction what brightens the screen from black. So yes color is defined its currently `color=255` on the program

Comment: @TedKleinBergman i added the original image drawing like thats what it draws when you use the program without resizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're resizing the screen you're blitting the scaled images just once and then goes back to blitting the original images. To resolve this you could rebind the images to their scaled version. If your images are pixel-based it might distort them, so you'll need to have a reference to the original image and transform it instead of transforming an already transformed image.

So in your `VIDEORESIZE`event you could for example do this:

```
spaceGUI = pygame.transform.scale(spaceGUI, event.dict['size'])
```

for every image, instead of blitting.

Comment: Ok that seems to work. But how could i use `pygame.transform.scale(spaceGUI, event.dict['size'])` for text and rectangles too? because my understandment of pygame isn't very great would help to understand the consept.

Comment: `transform.scale` works on `Surfaces`. Everything you put on the screen has to be represented by a Surface-object, hence you'll be able to use this for everything visible. Text is created by rendering a Surface with text on from a font-object, so it'll work the same as an image. Rect's are **not** used visually but rather to position Surfaces. If you want to change a Rect's size you could just do `rect.size = event.dict['size']` or use [`rect.inflate(x, y)`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.inflate) to change it's size by offset.

Comment: Yes that seems to as expected propely for `VIDEORESIZE` `rect.size = event.dict[`size`]` works perfectly.